# How come 1 is printed instead of 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested

I am confused as to why '0' is never printed when I print the value for 'i'. Why is this.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
for i in range(0,10):
  for z in range(i):
    print([i], end=' ')
```

Comment: You print 2 two times. You print 1 one time. You print 0 zero times.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I understand now. The 'z' iterations do not begin because the range in the nested loop is set at 0 through the first iteration so the following print statement does not execute. It takes 'i' to increase to 1 and now the 'z' variable can start participating because it has a value greater than 0.


**edit** you can print zero but you have to print it right after you initialize the first for loop, before the nested.

Answer (score 2):

Because `range(0)` has nothing for you to iterate through so you just don't iterate in that case:

```
for i in range(0): print(i)
```

prints nothing because it's like doing:

```
for i in []: print(i)
```

and you'd be able to see this with a little experimenting:

```
>>> list(range(0))
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

The range function in python yields/gives values up to (but not including) its argument. So `list(range(5))` will be `[0,1,2,3,4]`, and `list(range(0))` will be... `[]`

As you want to print `i` for each value in this empty list, you don't print `i` at all!

Hope this helps, and let me know if I did not explain it clear enough!

Answer (score 1):

if you modify your code like this :

```
for i in range(0, 10): 
    for z in range(0, i):
        print([z], end=' ')
    print('')
```

It prints :

```
[0]
[0] [1]
[0] [1] [2]
[0] [1] [2] [3]
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4]
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6]
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7]
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4] [5] [6] [7] [8]
```

Comment: @SMTH Sorry my friend, both my spare time and knowledge in multiprocessing are very limited. I couldn't offer any useful advice at all.

Answer (score 0):

because `range(0)` will give `[]`, so it is not printing